# How to provide access of Google Cloud Run website to company Active Directory?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, active-directory, gmail, google-cloud-run

I have deployed a website using Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Build with a yaml file like below:

```
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "my-app"
      - "--image"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/appcicd:latest"
      - "--region"
      - "europe-west2"
      - "--platform"
      - "managed"
      - "--allow-unauthenticated"
```

With the code above, I have allowed anyone who has the URL link to access the website.

How do I restrict the website access above to a company domain Active Directory for example? Assume the company domain is using Gmail account.

Thanks.

Comment: What's a active directory domain? A domain name? for instance `@active.directory.domain`?

Answer (score 0):

To implement authentication of Active Directory users in Cloud Run, you need to setup Google Cloud Identity Platform with [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#how_does_it_work) to verify the [identity token](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-admin-auth-api#id_token_verification) and get the user ID.

Check this documentation on [how to setup Microsoft users in GCIP](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/microsoft).

Additionally, if ever you want to stick on using all Google services, you can check this [article](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) on how to authenticate users with Google Sign-in.